# Why exactly was $\epsilon$ chosen to denote a very small quantity?

Tags: notation, math-history

I tried to search the defintion of $\epsilon$, but only got that it is the fifth letter in the Greek alphabet.

I want to know **why** it was chosen the way it was?

This is something not very obvious, unlike the symbol $\in$, which means **element of**. That makes sense because $\in$ looks like an $E$ which can stand for element.

But epsilon is just an alphabet letter, and so why was it chosen?

Comment: I think that $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ were chosen because they're consecutive letters in the Greek alphabet.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom first of all, sickass name. Secondly, I agree they are, make I want to know why specifcally those? Was it random? I don't see an english linkage like how $\in$ has

Comment: I've always thought of $\epsilon$ as error and $\delta$ as a small change (like $\Delta x$). I can't speak for Weierstrass and Bolzano.

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess error would make sense ...

Comment: I think $\delta$ was chosen because it sounds like the "d" in difference. Also the upper case, $\Delta$ was being used to indicate a small change in a quantity. After that, $\epsilon$ was chosen because it is the next Greek letter after $\delta$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530792/who-gave-you-the-epsilon

Comment: @stevengregory I agree that's likely it, but do you have a source on the use of $\Delta$?

Comment: @c   [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation) is the best I can do.

Comment: I don't know, but I like to think of $\varepsilon$ as standing for *error*.

Comment: See the post: [Who gave you the epsilon ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530792/who-gave-you-the-epsilon): Cauchy in his [1823 textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=uN5UAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover) used trhe Greek letters $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \ldots$ for "nombres très-petites" (very small numbers). In the first chapter he started using $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and in the proof of the Theorem (7th Lecture) he introduced $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. Thus, I think that there is no special "allusion" behind the choice of them.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82302/why-do-we-use-epsilon-and-delta

Comment: Just because....

Comment: @amWhy... funny you say that given your name includes the word "Why"